# How does ASP.NET Web API "sort" Request Headers into Header Collections?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I was trying to read the value of the `Content-Type` header in a custom delegating handler in ASP.NET Web API. When I queried the `request.Headers` collection, the header value wasn't in there. However, it was contained in `request.Content.Headers`. Other non-standard headers (such as `Content-Test`) starting with `Content-` were available in `request.Headers` only; `Content-Length`, on the other hand, could only be found within `request.Content.Headers`, just like `Content-Type`.

Is it correct to assume that Web API is putting all known content headers into the `request.Content.Headers` collection while putting all other headers into `request.Headers`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how the `HttpClient` was designed in the first place. Requests and responses are separate from the actual content hence content related cookies go into the `HttpContent.Headers` rather than `HttpRequestMessage.Headers`. Keeping the content headers with the content is a good way of separating the concerns, on the other hand, getting to the content headers is a bit more cumbersome.

Comment: Alright, that's what I assumed after trying this out. I have to admit that I found it a little counter-intuitive to not find all headers within `HttpRequestMessage.Headers`, though.

Comment: Actually if you think of it, it is logical. Request and the response have different headers while they both share the same headers for the content.

Comment: True, it does make sense if you put it like that. Thanks for the quick answer!